# python: datetime strftime not working properly

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to print a date time into a file in a particular format due to which I have formatting a datetime object using strftime function as below:

```
hFile = open("Test.csv", 'w')
for str in datelist:
   splitStr = str.split("_")
   dateTime = datetime.datetime(int(splitStr[0]), int(splitStr[1]), int(splitStr[2]), int(splitStr[3]), int(splitStr[4]), int(splitStr[6]))
   hFile.write(dateTime.strftime('%H:%M %d/%m/%Y'))
```

This for some of the cases works well and prints it in correct format but for some cases it prints it in the following format:

```
>1/4/2013 12:45
```

instead of

```
>12:45 1/04/2013
```

But when I only do:

```
>dateTime.strftime('%H %d/%m/%Y')
```

It doesn't switch the time and date in certain cases and prints it in correct format for all the cases. Any idea why is it happening?

**An Important observartion:**
Everything works fine when I remove the `:`. So, the below command works fine. Now that makes me more confused.

```
>dateTime.strftime('%H %M %d/%m/%Y')
```

works perfectly fine. Any idea what is the issue with putting `:` in the `strftime`?

Thanks.

Comment: How is the date time object getting created? Can you post some code sample of what you are doing?

Comment: @skar Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Can you provide `datelist`  to make your example independent?

Answer (score 0):

I created an equivalent sample which seems to work.

```
from datetime import datetime
a = datetime.now()
```

or

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime.now()


a.strftime('%H:%M %d/%m/%Y')

>>> '11:04 22/04/2015'
```